# preg_replace to make first character uppercase without using builtin functions like ucwords()

Tags: php

I have a string called `hello world` (fetching this data from database)

Expected output shoulb be:
`Hello World`

So far I have tried these below approaches with PHP:

```
$row['last_saved_by'] = preg_replace('/ ([a-z]{1})/', "ucwords(strtoupper('$1'))", "{$row['last_saved_by']}");
```

and

```
$row['last_saved_by'] = preg_replace_callback('/ ([a-z]{1})/', 'upper', $str);

    function upper($matches) {
      return strtoupper($matches[0]);
    }
```

I want this to be done using preg_replace without using ucwords or some other built in functions.

Comment: use ucwords(); function

Comment: Why is regex always the first thing people try to solve problems with?

Answer (score 2):

There are another simple ways to achieve this like function [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php). It changes the first character of each word in a string to uppercase.

```
echo ucwords($str);
```

Comment: You mean `ucwords` - no underscore.

Comment: Right @NigelRen

Answer (score 1):

Check out `ucwords()`. It converts the first character of each word in a string to uppercase.

```
print_r(ucwords(<your_string>));
```